# Is string::c_str() allowed to allocate anything on the heap?

Tags: c++, string

If I need to get a NUL-terminated `char` array out of a `std::string` in a situation where I need to be sure nothing will be allocated, is it safe to use `c_str` to do so? For example, if I'm inside a destructor and I want to copy some data from a `string` into a pre-allocated, fixed-size buffer, can I use `c_str` and be sure it won't throw anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard says that calling `c_str()` may invalidate references, pointers, and interators referring to the elements of the `string`, which implies that reallaocation is permitted (21.3/5 "Class template basic_string").

You might want to just call `string::copy()` to get your copy (you'll need to add the null terminator yourself if you need it).

Comment: The suggestion to use `string::copy()` was particularly useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No, the standard gives no such guarantee. The only guarantee in the C++ standard is that the returned value points to a `char` array with the same contents as the `std::string`, plus a nul-terminator.

So it would be standards-conforming for an implementation to store its internal representation in some way other than a C-string, and allocate a C-string on the fly when you call `c_str`, although I'm fairly certain that no widely used STL implementation actually does this.

Now, with respect to C++0x, I have heard (although I am at a loss for finding documentation for this at the moment), that one of the changes is going to be to require that `std::string` operate on contiguous storage (a similar requirement already exists for `std::vector`). So in that case, you could access the span from `&str[0]` through `&str[0]+str.length()-1` as if it were a C-string without a nul-terminator.

Comment: Regarding the requirement for contiguous storage, yes, C++0x N3126 says, in `21.4.1/5`, "The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously."

Answer (score 2):

The Standard is silent on this:

### 21.3.6 [lib.strings.ops]

> const charT * c_str () const ; 1
>   Returns: A pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of length size() +
>   1 whose first size() elements equal
>   the corresponding elements of the
>   string controlled by *this and whose
>   last element is a null character
>   specified by charT().
>
> 2 Requires: The program shall not
>   alter any of the values stored in the
>   array. Nor shall the program treat the
>   returned value as a valid pointer
>   value after any subsequent call to a
>   non-const member function of the class
>   basic_string that designates the same
>   object as this.

It could.  That said, Iv'e never seen any implementation that does.

If this is a concern for you, you may want to consider using `vector<char>` instead of `string`, and doing something like:

```
vector<char> chars;
// ...
char* my_str = &chars[0];
```

The trick here is knowing when & how to deal with the need for `'\0'`-terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

The standard all but explicitly says that a string can allocate memory when you call `c_str`. In particular, it says (§21.3/5):

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_string object:
>   [ ... ]
>   — Calling data() and c_str() member functions.

It gives permission for pointers, references and iterators to be invalidated *specifically* to allow an implementation to re-allocate the memory used to store the string when you call `c_str`.