# Does std::string really wrap up a C char array?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I always thought an `std::string` was implemented as an STL wrapper for a C char array string. But looking closely at the design, I've noticed that it doesn't give any hint or sign of being a wrapped up c-string. For all I know an `std::string` could be doing *anything* internally!

There is the `c_str()` method of course which I thought returned the internal char array, but how do I know if the method doesn't create a *new* c char array from whatever data it stores inside and return it?

Seriously, how has `std::string` been implemented? Is it (as it appears to be) just a wrapper for a C char array, or is it something else? Or a mixture of the two? Or even can become both conditionally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> For all I know an std::string could be doing anything internally!

For all *you* know. The standard, of course, describes and demands certain semantics that rule *anything* out. It says the following on the `basic_string` template:

`§21.4 [basic.string] p1`

> The class template `basic_string` describes objects that can store **a sequence consisting of a varying number of arbitrary char-like objects** with the first element of the sequence at position zero. Such a sequence is also called a “string” if the type of the char-like objects that it holds is clear from context. In the rest of this Clause, the type of the char-like objects held in a `basic_string` object is designated by `charT`.

And a "char-like object" is defined by the following text:

`§21.1 [strings.general] p1`

> This Clause describes components for manipulating sequences of any non-array POD (3.9) type. In this Clause such types are called *char-like types* , and objects of char-like types are called *char-like objects* or simply *characters*.

This effectively means that you can stuff anything you want into `basic_string`, as long as it's not an array and it is a POD (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/146452/500104) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/500104) for infos on what PODs are). These char-like objects are then manipulated with the help of character traits, which define the specific behaviour of and relationship between them.

---

> [...] but how do I know if the method doesn't create a new c char array from whatever data it stores inside and return it?

In C++03 exactly this was possible to do for the implementation, a known defect that has since been corrected in C++11:

`§2.4.1 [string.require] p5`

> The char-like objects in a `basic_string` object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.

See also these related questions:

- [Is string::c_str() allowed to allocate anything on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823058/is-stringc-str-allowed-to-allocate-anything-on-the-heap)
- [Is it legal to write to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760790/is-it-legal-to-write-to-stdstring)
- [Is it reasonable to use std::basic_string<t> as a contiguous buffer when targeting C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/how-bad-is-code-using-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer)

Comment: +1 + accept. Thanks. Wish I could give this a hundred upvotes.